# What do i do to get my bluetooth module to light up?

Tags: arduino-uno, hc-05, l293d

I'm very new to arduino and am doing my first project, a bluetooth run robot. When i plugged in my module to my laptop to upload the code, the module lights up, and afterwards, i was able to run it on my 12v battery. However, later on, my module stopped working suddenly. It came on once after that, but was on AT config and blinked out soon after. Is this problem because I have been using my battery for a month now without a recharge or because its connected to too many devices or because of a faulty bluetooth module

Comment: How is everything connected? Please show a wiring diagram

Comment: are you asking if your battery is dead?